# Domain of the generator of the Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, sobolev-spaces, markov-process

Let $B_t$ be the standard Brownain Motion on $\mathbb R$. It is known that its generator is 
$$Lf=\frac{1}{2}f''$$ and it is defined on function $f\in C^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$.

It is possible to define the generator $L$ on a bigger space, for istance for $f$ in the Sobolev space $H^2(\mathbb R)$?

Thank you very much

Comment: What does it have to do with Brownian motion and generators? You just have some operator, which you can close in $H^2(\mathbb R)$... Maybe there is some context? Why do you want to extend the "generator"?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is, why the generator of teh Brownian motion is defined on $C^2(\mathbb R)$ and not in a bigger space?

Comment: Actually, it is not even defined on $C^2(\mathbb R)$, but on $C^2_b(\mathbb R)$ (twice continuoulsy differentiable functions bounded together with first and second derivatives) or $C^2_0(\mathbb R)$ (twice continuoulsy differentiable functions vanishing on infinity together with first and second derivatives) for the sake of having a good functional-analytic approach (Hille-Yosida theory etc). For other approaches (e.g. Dirichlet forms) it can be defined on a "larger" space, e.g. Sobolev.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you suggest me a book in which they use the second approach with the Sobolev space?

Comment: Try Fukushima et al. *Dirichlet forms and symmetric Markov processes*

Comment: Thank you!!....